# Text positing weird on canvas

Tags: html, css

Novice question; trying to learn web design and i've come along way. However could somebody try and explain this to me.

This is how one particular section in my website looks:
[image: website screenshot]

I am trying to split the image 40% of the screen and the text in the remaining 60%. It's gone well, however I cannot figure out why the text appears at the bottom and not the top? I am guessing it is very simple, or have I just messed it up?

Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="about">
  <div class="about_img"></div>
    <div class="about_text">
      <h1>Some Text</h1>
      <p>Some supporting text</p>
</div>
</section>
```

And my CSS for the section:

```
.about{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    min-height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.about_img{
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("/assets/alex-image.JPG");
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 .about_text{
     width: 20%;
     display:inline-block;
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 50px;
 }
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information. I have also uploaded my site to http://www.alexwiley.co.uk

Thanks,

Comment: default alignment for inline-block elements is `baseline`

Comment: Use `vertical-align` to specify how you want your inline-block items to be aligned.

Comment: PERFECT! Knew it would be something that simple. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER, thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe).

Use vertical-align: top; to align the element to the top of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this css to the text to have it in the top :

```
vertical-align: top
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add `vertical-align: top` to the `<div class="about_text">` to align it vertically on top.

### Possible values

According to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp), other possible values you have are:

```
vertical-align: middle
```

The element is placed in the middle of the parent element

```
vertical-align: bottom
```

The bottom of the element is aligned with the lowest element on the line

```
vertical-align: {length}
```

Raises or lower an element by the specified length. Negative values are allowed

```
vertical-align: {X}%
```

Raises or lower an element in a percent of the "line-height" property. Negative values are allowed

```
vertical-align: sub
```

Aligns the element as if it was subscript

```
vertical-align: super
```

Aligns the element as if it was superscript

```
vertical-align: text-top
```

The top of the element is aligned with the top of the parent element's font

```
vertical-align: text-bottom
```

The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font

### Default

the default value is:

```
vertical-align: baseline
```

Align the baseline of the element with the baseline of the parent element.

### Answer

```css
.about{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  min-height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.about_img{
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.alexwiley.co.uk/assets/alex-image.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
.about_text{
  width: 20%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="about_img"></div>
  <div class="about_text">
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
    <p>Some supporting text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```